# SonarQube JS UT coverage is always zero. However, jscoverage.xml import looks good

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, mocha.js, sonarqube-scan, sonarjs

I'm using SonarQube 6.3.1 and I'm running jenkins to create SonarQube dashboard. 
So, I need to run jenkins job  to create js coverage report and import to SonarQube to create UT coverage.

By setting SonarQube Scanner in Jenkins, here is properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=xxxxxxManagement
sonar.projectName=XXXXXX Management
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=webapp

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=target/jscoverage/jscoverage.xml
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

In Jenkins, here is the report path and report context:
[image: report path and context]

Here is SonarQube report:
[image: Here is SonarQube report]

However, SonarQube dashboard shows JS UT coverage is 0

I'm wondering if sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths setting is wrong, so I have tried many ways
I have tried:

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./target/jscoverage/jscoverage.xml
```

I also tried:

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=/target/jscoverage/jscoverage.xml
```

but UT coverage is always zero

Since I can see report created correctly, I doubt if import to SonarQube fail, but no error log shows in Jenkins console.

---

6/29
Add new updates from my investigation, 
From Jenkins log,

```
INFO: Analysing [/var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/target/jscoverage/jscoverage.xml]
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor [javascript] (done) | time=1611ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=36ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: org.sonar.scanner.cpd.deprecated.DefaultCpdBlockIndexer@4644f3d4 is used for js
DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language js
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 16 files
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/Component.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/model/util.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/IncidentDetail.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/model/formatter.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/util/Validator.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/localService/mockserver.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/Attachments.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/model/models.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/HelpRequestOverview.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/NotFound.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/ErrorHandler.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/CreateIncident.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/BaseController.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/HelpRequestDetail.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/HelpRequests.controller.js
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for /var/jenkins_home/sharedspace/webapp/controller/App.controller.js
INFO: CPD calculation finished
```

From log, we can see there is no error message so I added shell script in Post Steps in Jenkins Job:

```
cd target/jscoverage
pwd
vi jscoverage.xml
```

and Jenkins log shows:

```
<coverage files="11" line-rate="0.7357294" lines-covered="348" lines-valid="473"[3;2Htimestamp="1498722804050">
<modules>
<module name="/Component.js" filename="/Component.js" line-rate="0.84210527" lin[6;1Hes-covered="16" lines-valid="19">
<lines>
<line number="1" hits="1"/>
<line number="8" hits="1"/>
<line number="10" hits="1"/>
<line number="24" hits="1"/>
<line number="27" hits="1"/>
<line number="30" hits="1"/>
<line number="32" hits="1"/>
<line number="35" hits="1"/>
<line number="36" hits="1"/>
<line number="39" hits="1"/>
<line number="49" hits="1"/>
<line number="51" hits="1"/>
<line number="61" hits="1"/>
<line number="63" hits="1"/>
<line number="64" hits="1"/>
...
```

From 2 pieces of log we can see that report looks good and SonarQube reads report succuessfully, and we can see UT cover file by file in the xml report, but UT coverage is still zero.

---

7/3
I have added dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>fr.sii.sonar</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-coverage-lcov</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and changed

```
<sonar.javascript.jscoverage.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/jscoverage/jscoverage.xml</sonar.javascript.jscoverage.reportPath>
```

from jscoverage.xml to jscoverage.**lcov**
but still not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the relevant portions of your analysis log. You should see lines that talk about coverage...

Comment: Thanks Ann, I have added log.

Answer (score 0):

The report your are trying to import looks like an xml file. For JavaScript, SonarQube supports coverage reports in LCOV format. See documentation : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import

Depending on the coverage tool you are using, there might be an option to generate the report in the LCOV format.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at Sonar -> admin -> General Settings -> Javascript, and I got that Sonar only support LCOV file for Javascript and does not support any other file format. So do you know what Jenkins plugin I need to install? And how to update pom.xml?

Comment: I have add more details in comments above.

Comment: Warren, the dependency you added is a different analyzer and you don't need that to import an .lcov file, the standard SonarJS analyzer is already trying to do it for you, but you are not providing a file in the right format.

This is not a matter of Jenkins plugin, or changing the extension of a file, it's a matter of generating the coverage report in the format (lcov) that Sonar can understand. Which code coverage library are you using? Can it generate a report in the correct format?

Comment: I have done further investigation and found that I need to create LCOV file through mocha-lcov-reporter. Github:https://github.com/StevenLooman/mocha-lcov-reporter

Comment: If you are using jscover, it looks like they support the lcov format on their own : --format=LCOV